# How to make arc with many faces looks smooth with subdivision modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm newbie. How to make this looks normal?

This is arc I tried to make smooth using subdivision modifier.
[image: this is arc I tried to make smooth using subdivision modifier.]

[image]

I also tried this trick but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here are 2 ways (destructive and not) to do it:

[image]
[image]